# disabling flip screen windows 7

Tags: windows-7

How do I disable the keyboard shortcut `ctrl`+`alt`+`down arrow` in windows 7 so that the screen is not rotated 180° when I use this shortcut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's Intel video driver feature, so try go to Intel Control Panel (right mouse click on Desktop) and look for "Enable Hot Keys" option.